# Mixing Supplements

Tags: supplements

Before training I first take BCAA an then creatine, after my training I first take a smaller amount of BCAA and then whey protein.

My question is, if I can mix the BCAA & Creatine powder in one bottle, instead of taking it separately? Same for BCAA & whey protein powder. Is there any use taking them separaterly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about mixing, just make sure flavors match. Creatine supplements are mostly have no flavor so you can mix any but most bcaa has fruit based flavors so maybe its not a good idea to mix it with whey unless they have flavor.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that BCAAs or individual amino acids ought NOT be taken with protein as it eradicates the specific benefits of the aminos alone. The two compete for absorption and the proteins win... or, the aminos are simply chained with the  protein's aminos.

BCAAs should be taken on an empty stomach before, during or after training (and upon awakening). Creatine is not an amino or protein so include it with the BCAAs and with the protein.

Sugar is beneficial, fueling muscle and brain cells... and supposedly "bringing" aminos and other nutrients into the cells as well.

Comment: Can you cite any research to back this up? It is the first time I'm hearing of it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can mix BCAAs and Creatine together.

No, there is no benefit of taking them separately.

Also, like CanESER said, Creatine (monohydrate, at least) doesn't have any flavor, so it definitely doesn't matter.